# HTTP request from PowerShell has wrong remote IP

Tags: networking, powershell, ip

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that performs an HTTP request. The request is handled by a PHP script which needs to know the IP address of the client. To this end, it reads `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

Now, the following strange behaviour occurs:

- When I use a service like whatismyip.com, my IP is `xxx.yyy.141.183`
- When I use a web browser to call my PHP script, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` returns the same IP as above, `xxx.yyy.141.183` (as expected).
- When I use the PowerShell script to call the very same PHP script, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` returns a different IP, namely `xxx.yyy.51.111`.

The PowerShell script is very simple:

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadString("http://example.net/myscript.php")
```

I observe this behavior being connected to my university's network. Therefore, I do not know any details about the network configuration. I noticed that different machines seem to have different IPs using the methods in bullet points 1 and 2 but they all have the same IP using the third method.

Question: How can I modify my PowerShell script to "behave like a web browser", i.e. to send a request where the remote address as seen by the server equals the remote address it sees when receiving the request from a web browser?

Bonus question: Why does this happen?

Comment: Where is the PHP being called from ? The `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is relative of course.. Also what does `ipconfig` say your IP is ? Most likely the `*.*.141.183` is your universitie's firewall.. But that's just speculation.

Comment: @Pogrindis Not sure if I understand your question. I'm sitting in front of my laptop, using the methods from bullet point 1-3 on after the other. So all 3 calls come from the same client. `ipconfig` gives my the `141.183` as my IPv4 address.

Comment: Well not really, the other two are running through the network, which will have it's own router/firewall rules etc, hitting the php directly (assuming its on your laptop) from your powershell does not route outside of your local machine.

Comment: @Pogrindis I guess all the requests pass through the university's network (what else?) and finally, they all definitely arrive at the server (which I observe in the logfiles). What is different about the PowerShell requests?

Comment: By any chance is this PowerShell Direct ?

Comment: @Pogrindis: There are no virtual machines involved, so I think the answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discovery that only Firefox made requests with the correct public IP `xxx.yyy.141.183` while IE and Chrome didn't, I found the following solution:

- The fact that different browsers behave differently implies that the problem is not directly related to PowerShell but stems from proxy settings.
- I realized that Firefox was set to "use the System's proxy settings". When I changed this to "detect proxy settings for the network automatically" (rough translation, sorry), Firefox (just like IE and Chrome) produced requests with the `xxx.yyy.51.111` IP.
- From this I concluded that PowerShell must be using a configuration that makes it detect proxy settings automatically. This conjecture is confirmed by the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.webclient.proxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1):

> The Proxy property identifies the IWebProxy instance that communicates with remote servers on behalf of this WebClient object.The proxy is set by the system using configuration files and the Internet Explorer Local Area Network settings.To specify that no proxy should be used, set the Proxy property to the proxy instance returned by the GetEmptyWebProxy method.

- As I don't want to change the system configuration and as `GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy` has been deprecated, I now successfully use the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1141189/2706569): Simply set the `proxy` property to `null`.

  ```
  $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
  $wc.Proxy = $null
  $wc.DownloadString("http://example.net/myscript.php")
  ```